# Suitescript 2.0 submit data on different thread

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a script which is taking 6 seconds to run. I removed a line of code which submits some data at the end before serving a dialog to the user, and the time dropped to 1.5 secs. This submitted data is not vital for the user but it does need to be submitted. Is there a way I can submit this data in the background while serving the dialog to the user.

Comment: Are you submitting data in client script? Client side scripts are alot slow compared to Server-Side scripts, If possible can you submit data server-side? or can you use Map/Reduce or Scheduled scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Promise API available in NetSuite, it will create a different thread for each request.